# loading ES6 files locally

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

I have an application, which uses ES6 modules, if I run it on server using Webstorm everything is okay, but without server it won`t work.
I got this messages for all files:

> "Access to Script at 'file:///C:/Users/nameuser/Desktop/project/FileLoader.jsx' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

How can I solve this problem without using server?

Earlier I saved all React components to the index.html, but it is really difficult to work with 3000 lines of code in one file. Employer doesn't want to use server at this moment.

I tried to use this chrome command, but got no results

```
google-chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: Perhaps use a CDN?

Comment: run your application on a serve

Comment: But where do you run your application when you're not in Webstorm? Even if you only run it on a local machine it's advisable to install a `localhost` server and run your project from there. It's free and most operating systems already have it built in, you only have to activate it.